# how to run servlets in XAMPP server

Tags: 14.04, server, java, xampp

I had installed xampp in ubuntu 14.04. now i want to have servlet functionality. I searched in net, everyone saying use the tomcat but i want to do it in xampp is it possible if yes how to do that procedure please? thanks in advance.

Comment: Dear ashok, this is askubuntu.com not xampp.com, please be more specific if you have any troubles with Ubuntu. What are doing? What is your exact problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Everyone" is right ;) To use servlets, you need to a web container. XAMPP includes the Apache HTTP server as a webserver, and the Apache HTTP server does not offer a web container. You need something like Tomcat or JBoss/WildFly.